# How to create Django Model with Many-To-Many Parents-Children Relationship?

Tags: python, django, relationship

I already know, that I can achieve ForeignKey Parent-Children relationship within the same model, that allows to create relations with 1 parent = multiple children. But how can I accomplish Many-To-Many relationship within the same model ? At this moment I wrote and tested this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', blank=True
    )
```

And it works, but not as I expected. What it does is:

```
john = Person.objects.get(id=1)
sam = Person.objects.get(id=2)

>>> john.parents.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Alex>, <Person: Peter>, <Person: Sam>]>
>>> sam.parents.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: John>]>
```

As you can see, Sam was supposed to be child of John, not his child and parent at the same time. What I want is to get John when I'm retrieving sam.parents.all() But not to get Sam when I'm retrieving john.parents.all()

Is there a way to accomplish what I want ? Or that's not gonna work with this logic at least ? Do I have to create second separate model withing the same app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) show, you need to set `symmetrical=False` on that field to prevent it automatically using the same relation in reverse. To make things even clearer, you can set `related_name` to something relevant like "children".

```
parents = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='children'
)
```

Now you can do `john.children.all()` to get Sam.

(Note, because people often seem confused by this, `related_name` is not *required* here; but the default would be `person_set` which in this case is not as clear as `children`.)